# How probabilistic quantum mechanics explains why all free electrons at rest are identical?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, standard-model

All photons are not identical varying with wavelength.

However all free electrons in our Universe at rest are identical having all the same exact Compton wavelength, ~511KeV energy, spin magnetic moment etc.

Sounds to me like a pretty deterministic phenomenon.

What is the explanation presented by probabilistic Quantum Mechanics and the standard model about this peculiar phenomenon?

Answer (score 1):

For a given particle the free particle states are uniquely identified by their momentum $\mathbf p$. So the appropriate statement to make here is:

- all electrons with the same momentum are identical
- all photons with the same momentum are identical

The difference between electrons and photons that for electrons the momentum is given by:

$$ p = m_e v \tag{1} $$

while for photons the momentum is:

$$ p = \frac{h}{\lambda} \tag{2} $$

This is not specifically a difference between electrons and photons but a difference between massive and massless particles. Any massive particle has the equation (1) for the momentum and any massless particle the equation (2) for the momentum.

For completeness we should note that even for massive particles we can write the momentum as:

$$ p = \frac{h}{\lambda_b} \tag{3} $$

where $\lambda_b$ is the de Broglie wavelength. The similarity between equations (2) and (3) makes it even clearer that the two types of particles are treated in the same way.

The mass of all fundamental particles of the same type is the same because they are all states of the same quantum field. For example all (free) electrons are states of the electron field. For fermions like electrons the mass is determined by the Yukawa coupling of the quantum field to the Higgs field not by the momentum of the state. For the gauge bosons like photons it's a little more complicated, but the mass is still a property of the field not of individual states.

Comment: The question could be also rephrased as, why all free electrons have exactly the same rest mass?

Comment: @Markoul11 I've extended my answer to respond to your comment.

Answer (score 1):

This is an assumption, a generalization of experience, where most cases of electron-like behaviour in experiments are well explained by the standard theory using the simplest assumption on mass - that all the electrons have the same mass. The hypothesis that some electrons may have slightly different mass so we cannot detect the difference cannot be easily proven wrong, but it is not very attractive, as there is no evidence for electrons having different masses.

Rare electron-like particles that are heavier than the standard electron mass 9.1e-31 kg were discovered, and were named muons(heavier than electron) and tauons(heavier than muon). These are sometimes considered different kinds of electrons, but since they have different mass and also different magnetic behaviour, they are not usually called electrons. They are very rare in ordinary matter, but they can be detected in cosmic rays or near particle accelerators by particle detectors.

Answer (score 0):

One point of view that you could take is that it is the electron *field* that is fundamental. Each electron (particle) corresponds to an excited state of this single electron field, and the properties of these excited states are constrained by the Lorentz symmetry of spacetime. For example, they all have to have the same mass and spin angular momentum.

Arguably, the "determinism" you are talking about is the contrapositive of the [totalitarian principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totalitarian_principle) that "anything not forbidden is compulsory." So if you see something that definitely *doesn't* happen—like electrons having different masses—it must be forbidden for some reason. Often that reason has to do with a symmetry of the theory.